# Mongoose Aggregate Unwind Array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have in db such an Array called "schedule", where "dayOfWeek"(enum) is day of week, and "timeOfDay" is bit mask.

```
"schedule": [
    {"dayOfWeek": 1 ,"timeOfDay": 120 },
    {"dayOfWeek": 2 ,"timeOfDay": 120 },
    {"dayOfWeek": 4 ,"timeOfDay": 248 }
]
```

As a search query I'm sending this:

```
"schedule": [
    {"dayOfWeek": 1 ,"timeOfDay": 120 },
    {"dayOfWeek": 4 ,"timeOfDay": 248 }
]
```

How can I get users with the schedule that matches this search params?

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried so far

Comment: you didnt provide user